# ODBC connection re establishes after application pool recycle

Tags: iis-6, odbc, database-connection, application-pool

I have a web service application which connects to databases through odbc sql native client and SQL Server drivers. all of a sudden the application stopped connecting to the database throwing the error 08001. But when i did the application pool recycle it started working. Now it is happening intermittently and became a headache for me. It cant be a memory problem as it happened immediately after app pool reclycle once. but agian got corrected after one more app pool recycle. i dont know what is happening as none of the error logs give any clue:(. Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

the first step is to be able to diagnose what is going on. You cannot fix what you cannot measure. To do this I would enable pooling in the data source console for the driver, then add the counters to the performance monitor to see what the connection pool is doing.

I'm not sure what the realtionship between IIS applocation pool processes and odbc connections is but we are seeing some unexpected behaviour in this area. Also the odbc connection performance counters are visible if I connect to the driver through a locally installed console application but I cannot see any performance counter activity for connections made via the web service app pool in IIS? ODD!?